# How do I share data between repeated elements in React?

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to create an expandable card component using React. I've set it up as below. It all works right now, I can tap on a card to expand it, and tap on it again to collapse it. Each card has its own state variable 'expanded'

```
var ExpandableListItem = React.createClass({
toggleCard: function(){
    var self = this
    this.setState({
        expanded: !self.state.expanded
    })
},

getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        expanded: false
    }
},

render: function(){
    return (
        <Card onTouchTap={this.toggleCard}>
            <CardText>
                {this.state.expanded ? 'Expanded Card' : 'Normal Card'}
            </CardText>
        </Card>
    )
}
})

var CardList = React.createClass({
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.repeatEntity.map(function(element, index) {
                return (
                    <ExpandableListItem text={element[index].week}></ExpandableListItem>
                )}
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
})
```

What I want to have is, only one card open at a time, that is, if one is open and you tap on another one, the first must close.

I've tried having a global 'expanded' variable to handle this, but the state variables are not two-way bound (as in Angular), so I can't change the value of one card's state from another one.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**: Let the parent component handle all expanded states.

**HOW?** Save an `expanded` state foreach item in your parent component (`CardList`). You can save the states in an separate array with the same length as `repeatEntity` and map them, for example with the index to the correct entity.

```
array = [true, false, false]; // [0. expanded state, 1. ..., 2. ...]
entities = [{...}, {...}, {...}]; // [0. entity, 1. ..., 2. ...]
```

Alternatively you can add a variable `expanded` to each `entity`. Next you have to implement a callback function that takes the neccessary information to identify the toggled `entity`, as parameter. This would be the index or the `entity` object itself. Then, the callback function can change the matching `expanded` state of the passed `entity`.

```
handleCardItemToggle(entityIndex) {
    const expandedStates = this.state.entityStates;

    // set all values to 'false'

    expandedStates[entityIndex] = !expandedStates[entityIndex]; // toggle expanded-state of item

    this.setState({
        entityStates: expandedStates
    });
}
```

At least you have to pass the callback and index to all items.

```
render: function(){
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.repeatEntity.map(function(element, index) {
                return (
                    <ExpandableListItem id={index} isExpanded={this.state.entityStates[index]} handleToggle={this.handleCardItemToggle} text={element[index].week}></ExpandableListItem>
                )}
            )}
        </div>
    )
}


// in ExpandableListItem
toggleCard() {
    this.props.handleToggle(this.props.id);
}
```

**NOTE**: Maybe there are some syntactical or semantical errors. Nevertheless, the approach should solve your problem.

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much!
I spent a good hour trying to properly understand your answer and why it works. Definitely improves my understanding of React :)