# Create rich form components to expose value to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After having worked with React.js a couple of days, I have written most of my forms like the following (as exemplified in the [official tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html)):

```
React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value;
    // do something with the value
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" ref="text" defaultValue="foo" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

However, I have recenctly discovered a weakness of this approach where I am not capable to write rich form components to be used in forms that are built up by such components such as:

```
var RichInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="someStyle">
        <input type="text" ref="text" defaultValue="foo" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.text).value;
    // do something with the value
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <RichInput />
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Now I am wondering. After looking through available resources, I found the following approach to be used to overcome this limitation:

```
var RichInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="someStyle">
        <input type="text" value="foo" onChange={this.props.callback} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = this.state.text
    // do something with the value
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {text: 'foo'};
  }
  updateText: function(value) {
    this.setState({text: value});
  }
  render: function () {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <RichInput callback={this.updateText} />
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Is this the canonical solution to writing modularized form components? I am wondering as this does seem like a lot of overhead to me. I need to write extra functions **and** I need to make the component state-full what drives me a bit away from adapting this solution. Also, I wonder about performance as I really do not need to update the value on every change but only on (and in case of) form submission.

One possibility I found was to use:

```
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.rich.refs.text);
```

given that the `RichInput` has `ref="rich"` defined on it. But then again, the documentation of React says that *refs* should not be considered puplic API and be accessed outside of a component.

Comment: you can also do `this.refs.rich.getDOMNode().value`. also not really sure what your question is? are you asking how you should handle the actions?

Comment: This does not work when trying it out for my example. I wonder what the canonical way is to read a child's form value in React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I built my abstract `Input` component. I use it for various purposes (whenever I require the user to input something and I want to handle the action later) (example with ES6/7 with some bootstrap styling):

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';

export default class Input extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    buttonText: PropTypes.string,
    onButtonClick: PropTypes.func
  }

  constructor() {
    super();

    this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
    this._handleKeyUp = this._handleKeyUp.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='Input'>
        <div className='input-group'>
          <input type='text' className='form-control' placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                 ref='inputBox' onKeyUp={this._handleKeyUp}
          />
          <span className='input-group-btn'>
            <form onSubmit={this._handleClick}>
              <button className='btn btn-success' type='submit'>{this.props.buttonText}</button>
            </form>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  _handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let value = this.refs.inputBox.getDOMNode().value;
    this.props.onButtonClick(value);
    value = null;
  }

  _handleKeyUp(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this._handleClick(e);
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the `Parent` component you can initialize it like:

```
<Input placeholder='Enter something'
       buttonText='Submit'
       onButtonClick={this._handleButtonClick}
/>
```

and handle the `_handleButtonClick`:

```js
_handleMakeSearch(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a commonly solution to create very small components and one wrapper (parent component) that handles all states of his subcomponents, because the states of these subcomponents often depends on the state of other subcomponents.

So you are right, the wrapper/parent component will have a (lot of) overhead, but this way your "real" components are more modular.

```
var RichInput = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="someStyle">
                <input type="text" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

React.createClass({
    handleSubmit: function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = this.state.value;
        // do something with the value
    },

    getInitialState() {
        return {value: 'foo'};
    }

    updateValue(value) {
        this.setState({value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <RichInput value={this.state.value} onChange={this.updateValue} />
                <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156532/how-do-i-share-data-between-repeated-elements-in-react/31158058?noredirect=1#comment50329554_31158058) is an other question/answer, where you can see an example/use case. A parent component that handles all states of his subcomponents, where each state depends on each other. Maybe it helps to understand the benefits of this approach.